# How to create multiple foreign keys from one table to another if table1 contains multiple fields with fk to the same column of table2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have "info" table with some fields that point to "id" column of "file_uploads" table. Also I third table with fk to "file_uploads", lets call it "another_table".
How can I describe relationships in EF fluent api to use Linq Join or Include Queries?

```
InfoRecord {
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public long File1Id {get; set;}
    public long File2Id {get; set;}
    public long File3Id {get; set;}

    public List<FileUploadRecord> Files {get; set;}
}

FileUploadRecord {
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public long Url {get; set;}

    public InfoRecord Info {get; set;}
}

AnotherTableRecord {
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public long ImageId {get; set;}

    public long FileUploadRecord Image { get; set; }
}
```

I know that I can create simple raw sql query with join and it will work, but It doesn't work with Linq .Include or .Join.
I've tried to solve it by different ways, bu EF throw errors about bad FK relations.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? And what is the problem? what kind of error did you get?

Comment: This is a one-to-many relationship. You don't need multiple columns on `InfoRecord`. You just to point on `FileUploadRecord` to a `InfoRecord`. Then you can achieve `.Include` to load the files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tweak your models a little bit. Right now, the `InfoRecord` table has three columns pointing to the files table. The problem with that is: What if tomorrow you need to support more files? Adding more columns is not optimal. The process of fixing this is what's called [Database Normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php).

If `InfoRecord` needs "several columns to point to an id" on `FileUpload`, you have a `one-to-many` relationship - One `InfoRecord` can have one or more files. We can achieve normalization using 3 tables:

1 - `FileUpload` (the actual files, most basic entity. No relationships here.)

```
public class FileUpload
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

2 - `InfoRecord` - As your question, a InfoRecord can have many files:

```
public class InfoRecord
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FileUploadRecord> Files { get; set; }
}
```

And lastly, the entity that "glues" them together:

3 - `FileUploadRecord` - It has an `FK` to `FileUpload` and to `InfoRecord`

```
public class FileUploadRecord
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // FK to InfoRecord. Usefull for update scenarious
    // without having to load the whole entity.
    public long InfoRecordId { get; set; }

    public InfoRecord InfoRecord { get; set; }

    // FK To the actual file upload
    public long FileId { get; set; }

    public FileUpload FileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can configure it using the `FluentAPI` like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure the Entity that "glues" InfoRecord and FileUploads. 
    // One InfoRecord can have many files, so we need a table to store that relationship.
    modelBuilder.Entity<FileUploadRecord>()
        .HasOne(s => s.InfoRecord)
        .WithMany(g => g.Files)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.InfoRecordId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<FileUploadRecord>()
        .HasOne(p => p.FileUpload)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.FileId);
}
```

And to query using `.Include` like you wanted is easy now. The query below loads all `InfoRecords` with each respective files.

```
var recordsWithFiles = context.InfoRecords
                    .Include(p => p.Files)
                    .ThenInclude(p => p.FileUpload);
```

This is how the DB schema will look like:
[image]

As per the "another_table", looks like it's a simple `one-to-one` relationship so, you can just use plain [EF Core Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#conventions) for it. Of course `.Include` also works here.

```
public class AnotherTableRecord
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // FK To the actual file upload
    public long ImageId { get; set; }

    public FileUpload Image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can achieve the same by just adding to FileUploadRecord table in your scheme 2 columns: "info_record_id" and "another_table_record_id". And set fk from this columns to InfoRecord.Id and AnotherTableRecord.Id correspondently and one of this column always will be null(because file belongs to one of entity: Info or AnotherTable). So I don't need additional table for these approach. 
But It's looks like an ugly solution.:(
Or may be I got you wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. `Info` and `AnotherTable` are two separated tables that "reference" somehow files. `Info` as per your description need to reference more than 1 file, so that's why I introduced another table (one-to-many). `AnotherTable` also, as per your description only has 1 column, so you don't need another table for that (one-to-one). `FileUploadRecord ` is only used for `Info` to be able to have a info record with multiple files.

Comment: That's how you solve these kind of problems. It's just plain database normalization. Having `File1Id , File2Id, File3Id` is bad. Again, what if your requirements changes and now you need to support adding 4 files to an `Info`? What do you do? Change the database again? Often, EF gives you hints of something else wrong with your DB model. Your inability to using `Include` like you said just indicates that your DB model is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I simplified example too much. I really have restricted number of different files(like avatar, logo, some specific pdf docs, etc). So I need to have some context wrap about file. I can got it by adding some additional info to file_upload_record(and I believe that this is bad way) or I can create column in appropriate table(info_table) that describe this file(like LogoFileId, AvatarFileId, etc). I choose the second way. 
Would be happy if you point me to another way.:)